# decoding/decrypting the website URL

Tags: .net

I have seen that some website uses the passed parameters in encrypted/encoded format.
is it possible to decode/decrypt the url to plain text?

Comment: suppose i want to decode this string hY_LDoIwEEW_yPS2KVCWYKU0KRBREdkYFsY0EXBh_H7LThofc5cnZ-4M6YjL2D_ttX_YaexvpCVdeF6rJOeRAVQcUmiUG2OKmiFjjp_eeEULgDV7KotUMgi-sD3KqWcLmQmwNAj1FhLQwR_7OF_7u33BP-yfOb5MAt-vOHPfR3VMVUPFDqTMp-FC7sOhhdWrF4hgtLc!/dl3/d3/L3dDb0EvUU5RTGtBISEvWUZSdndBISEvNl9DR0FINDdMMDBHOEk3MEk4UjJDM1E4MTBHMQ!!/

Comment: hi sathish check the link of my answer you will get your answer

Comment: hi Pranay - could not run the code given in your link.. can you pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can encode and decode the url querystring data.

use

```
Server.UrlDecode()  - to decode data
and 
Server.URLEncode()  - to encode data
```

for encryption

[Query string encryption for ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/QueryStringEncryptionNET.aspx)

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking about HTTP encoded characters, but rather encrypted data included in the query string.

Comment: @Andrew Cooper - provided link for encryption

Comment: hY_LDoIwEEW_yPS2KVCWYKU0KRBREdkYFsY0EXBh_H7LThofc5cnZ-4M6YjL2D_ttX_YaexvpCVdeF6rJOeRAVQcUmiUG2OKmiFjjp_eeEULgDV7KotUMgi-sD3KqWcLmQmwNAj1FhLQwR_7OF_7u33BP-yfOb5MAt-vOHPfR3VMVUPFDqTMp-FC7sOhhdWrF4hgtLc!/dl3/d3/L3dDb0EvUU5RTGtBISEvWUZSdndBISEvNl9DR0FINDdMMDBHOEk3MEk4UjJDM1E4MTBHMQ!!/

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  If you have the decryption key.

These URLs are usually generated on the server and include encrypted information.  It's a mechanism for maintaining state between requests to the server.  As it's only the site server that has the encryption key there's no way for you to decrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between encryption and encoding. if the URL parameters are encrypted, only that party can decrypt who knows which algorithm has been used in encryption and also know the keys. On the other hand, encoding is mostly used to safely transmit the URL, so it can be decoded easily.